# trouble with a simple batch script in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm making a little bat script that renames all of the files in a folder to a jpg format for after I transfer them into the folder. This is what I have so far --

```
cd C:\Users\master\Pictures\Background Images
ren *.* *.jpg
echo "Done"
pause
```

I'm not that skilled in batch so I would like for it to take the files and rename them, but often there are duplicates so I get an error code that looks like this --

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file
>   cannot be found.

If that happens I would like the script to delete the duplicate file.
Also, There are pictures that I don't want in the file that gets copied over sometimes. All of the pictures I want have a dimension of 1920x1080 I would like to delete all of the other files in the folder that are not of this dimension size.

Thanks let me know if you know the solution to my problem.

Comment: What program are you using to read the metadata from the file?  Batch-files have no way to read the properties of image file or audio files. I recommend using the [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for that.

Comment: You can have multiple files with the same name but different extension in the same directory. It seems to me that `image.bmp` and `image.tif` and `image.jpeg` will all end up fighting for the `image.jpg` name. These aren't necessarily duplicate files so deleting two of those three files seems crazy!

Comment: Since Windows Explorer shows jpg file dimensions, it must be possible to get them without using a third-party application. And indeed it is: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/ (using Powershell and the Shell.Application COM object).

Comment: @Compo The folder I have images in all has the same extension the new files that are added to the directory have no extension at all but some of them are duplicates to files that already exist. By renaming it to a jpg file extension type they become executable and any file that already exists is ignored.